# Find unique ids between two collections in mongodb

Tags: java, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am new to mongoDB and trying to make a query to find out unique ids in a collection based on other collection.

**Collection1:**

```
[{
id: 123,
name: xyz
},
{
id: 234,
name: abc
},
{
id: 345,
name: pqr
}]
```

**Collection2 :**

```
[{
id: 123,
status: y
},
{
id: 789,
status: n
},
{
id: 345,
status: y
}]
```

The result I am looking for is to get the unique elements in **Collection1** based on ids from **Collection2**. Here in the above example below is the desired result as the id 234 is present in **Collection1** but not in **Collection2**.

```
    {
    id: 234,
    name: abc
    }
```

Also I want to know the count of records matching. Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform `$lookup` on collection two and filter out documents where a match was found using `$match` stage.

There is an option stage `$unset` which will remove the newly created `foundCol2Docs` key from lookup stage which will work only on MongoDB version  >= 4.2  Or you can replace it with `$project` stage altogether.

The below query is what you are looking for.

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Collection2",
      "let": {
        "sourceId": "$id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$id",
                "$$sourceId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "id": 1,
            
          }
        },
        
      ],
      "as": "foundCol2Docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "foundCol2Docs": [],
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "foundCol2Docs": 0
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_3rCQQ5-uTK)

To get the count of result, replace the last stage with `$count`

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Collection2",
      "let": {
        "sourceId": "$id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$id",
                "$$sourceId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "id": 1,
            
          }
        },
        
      ],
      "as": "foundCol2Docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "foundCol2Docs": [],
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "count"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W7SKVnZ1DPe)

For a more optimized solution which works better with MongoDB 3.6, index the `id` key on collection2 and use the below query.

```
db.Collection2.createIndex({"id": 1})
```

**Query:**

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Collection2",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "foundCol2Docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "foundCol2Docs": [],
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "count"
  }
])
```

Comment: I tried to execute the above query in robo3T and getting error : `Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$unset'",
 "code" : 40324,
 "codeName" : "Location40324"
} : aggregate failed`

Comment: It seems like you are using MongoDB version < 4.2   I have edited the answer by replaced the last aggregation stage with `$project` and it should work fine now. If you are still facing problems, remove the last `$project` stage

Comment: Above worked, please let me know if I can also get just count of results, by adding count() ?

Comment: @Jet yes you can. You just have the replace the last stage with `$count` stage. I have updated the answer for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the update but the query keep running since last 30mins :-(

Comment: what version of MongoDB are you running? Also what's the size of collection 1 and 2? I will give an optimized query accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240470/discussion-between-jet-and-hhharsha36).